# playframework scala controller returns AnyContentAsEmpty

Tags: scala, playframework

I send a post to my playframework backend and when I want to print the body I got the Message AnyContentAsEmpty

My controller lools like this:

```
def createProcess = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit  request =>

println(request.body)
Ok("s")
}
```

my route looks like this

```
POST            /process                             @controllers.ProcessesController.createProcess()
OPTIONS         /process                             @controllers.ProcessesController.createProcess()
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: This usually happens when the body of your request is empty. What should the content be?

Comment: I tried to send a Post or Opions Request wth postman ... there should be a json in the request

Comment: any further hints?

Comment: Well if I do the same and then do something like `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://localhost:9000/p -d '{"greetings": "ciao"}'` I see  that `println(request.body.asJson)` correctly prints out `Some({"greetings":"ciao"})`

What version of Play are you using? What does your POST look like?

Comment: I'm using play 2.5

Comment: changed my function like above. Now when I do it from postman it works. ... but frontend not there I got an error

Comment: `OPTIONS http://localhost:9000/process 400 (Bad Request)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?14ed:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?14ed:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?91bc:52
new:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/process. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400`

Comment: Have a look at Play's documentation about CSRF/CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

in application.conf

```
# Global fliters
play.http.filters=helpers.Filters

play.filters.cors {
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
  preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

in filters.scala

```
package helpers

import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter

class Filters @Inject()(corsFilter: CORSFilter)
  extends DefaultHttpFilters(corsFilter)
```